# Solving two coupled ODEs with delta function sources

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

I am interested in solving two coupled ODEs for two functions $f(r)$ and $g(r)$ of the following form:

$$r(1-g(r))+(r^2+1)\frac{f'(r)}{2f(r)}=E\delta(r-r_0)$$

$$rf(r)[2r(g(r)-1)g(r)+(r^2+1)g'(r)]=E\delta(r-r_0)$$

How can I approach this problem? I tried to think about using Green's functions, but wasn't sure how to proceed because both $g(r)$ and $f(r)$ appear in one equation.

Comment: Can you solve them with the right hand sides being $0$ instead of $E\,\delta(r-r_0)$?

Comment: One particular solution if the RHS is zero is $f(r)=g(r)=1$.

Comment: You can solve  for $log(f)$ in terms of g using the first equation and then you can substitute in the second, but it looks like a non linear mess, and Greens functions don't help if the equation is non linear.

Comment: Can you find the *general* solutions for the homogeneous system (i.e. with the right hand sides being $0$)?

Comment: I think that I have found the general solutions for the homogeneous system. Are there any requirements on $f$ and $g$ that you haven't mentioned? Shall they for example both be positive?

Comment: That's great, thank you! Yes, the context I am solving this in is Einstein's equations, so I think they both have to be positive.

Answer (score 2):

#### Homogeneous solutions

When the right hand side vanishes the second equation implies
$$
2r(g(r)-1)g(r)+(r^2+1)g'(r) = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{g'(r)}{g(r)(1-g(r))} = \frac{2r}{r^2+1}
.
$$
This can easily be integrated using partial fraction decomposition in the left hand, giving
$$
\ln |g(r)(1-g(r))| = \ln(x^2+1) + C_1,
$$
where $C_1$ is a constant.

Solving for $g(r)$ then gives
$$
g(r) = \frac12\left(1\pm\sqrt{1+C(r^2+1)}\right),
$$
where $C$ is another constant.

Setting $f(r)=e^{h(r)}$ the first equation becomes (still with a vanishing right hand side)
$$
2r(1-g(r)) + (r^2+1) h'(r) = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
h'(r) = -\frac{2r}{r^2+1}(1-g(r))
= -\frac{2r}{r^2+1} \frac12\left(1\mp\sqrt{1+C(r^2+1)}\right)
.
$$
With the help of Wolfram Alpha the integral of this was found to be
$$
h(r) = \frac12\ln(r^2+1) \pm \left( \sqrt{1+C(r^2+1)} - \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{1+C(r^2+1)} \right) + D,
$$
where $D$ is a constant.